# Best approach to handle large files on django website

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, large-files

Good morning all.

I have a generic question about the best approach to handle large files with Django.

I created a python project where the user is able to read a binary file (usually the size is between 30-100MB). Once the file is read, the program processes the file and shows relevant metrics to the user. Basically it outputs the max, min, average, std of the data.

At the moment, you can only run this project from the cmd line. I'm trying to create a user interface so that anyone can use it. I decided to create a webpage using django. The page is very simple. The user uploads files, he then selects which file he wants to process and it shows the metrics to the user.

Working on my local machine I was able to implement it. I upload the files (it saves on the user's laptop and then it processes it). I then created an S3 account, and now the files are all uploaded to S3. The problem that I'm having is that when I try to get the file (I'm using smart_open (https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/)) it is really slow to read the file (for a 30MB file it's taking 300sec), but if I download the file and read it, it only takes me 8sec.

My question is: What is the best approach to retrieve files from S3, and process them? I'm thinking of simply downloading the file to my server, process it, and then deleting it. I've tried this on my localhost and it's fast. Downloading from S3 takes 5sec and processing takes 4sec.

Would this be a good approach? I'm a bit afraid that for instance if I have 10 users at the same time and each one creates a report then I'll have 10*30MB = 300MB of space that the server needs. Is this something practical, or will I fill up the server?

Thank you for your time!

**Edit**
To give a bit more of a context, what's making it show is the f.read() line. Due to the format of the binary file. I have to read the file in the following way:

```
name = f.read(30)
unit = f.read(5)
data_length = f.read(2)
data = f.read(data_length)   <- This is the part that is taking a lot of time when I read it directly from S3. If I download the file, then this is super fast.
```

Answer (score 1):

All,

After some experimenting, I found a solution that works for me.

```
with open('temp_file_name', 'wb') as data:
    s3.download_fileobj(Bucket='YOURBUCKETNAME', Key='YOURKEY', data)

read_file('temp_file_name')
os.remove('temp_file_name')
```

I don't know if this is the best approach or what are the possible downfalls of this approach. I'll use it and come back to this post if I end up using a different solution.

The problem with my previous approach was that f.read() was taking too long, the problem seems to be that every time I need to read a new line, the program needs to connect to S3 (or something) and this is taking too long. What ended up working for me, was to download the file directly to my server, read it, and then deleting it once I read the file. Using this solution I was able to get the speeds that I was getting when working on a localserver (reading directly from my laptop).

If you are working with medium size files (30-50mb) this approach seems to work. My only concern is if we try to download a really large file if the server will run out of disk space.